# Find $(m,n,p)$ with $m+n+p=2020$ such that $x/y+y/x=m$, $y/z+z/y=n$, $z/x+x/z=p$ has at least one real solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is modified question from the [Matematičko fizički list](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/mfl/) (which used 2012 instead of 2020).

> Find all positive integer triples $(m, n, p)$, where $m+n+p = 2020$ such that system below has at least one real solution.
>
> $$
> \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} = m \qquad
> \frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y} = n \qquad
> \frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{z} = p
> $$

One solution is $(2, 1009, 1009)$. Are there other possibilities?

Comment: The question is modified question from the Matematičko fizički list which is not available online.

Comment: Original question has $m+n+p=2012$.
Publication: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/mfl/

Comment: Be advised that the community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) In particular, since this is a modification of a previous question: Do you have a solution to the original? (If so, please include it.) Is there reason to believe that simply changing $2012$ to $2020$ doesn't affect the complexity of the solution? etc. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head.

Comment: @Blue  I have thought occasionally of posting a problem without wanting an answer but for the benefit of students' interest and learning.  It has been made clear not to do any such thing nor have I found the stack a friendly place where I would discuss my interests.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: I hope I'm not contributing to unfriendliness! That said, Math.SE is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or educational blog; its architecture isn't suited to for-fun posts, and its traffic would bury them, anyway. I'll note that it's annoying to invest what could be *hours* of effort crafting a comprehensive solution to a problem —formatting elaborate equations, drawing intricate diagrams, honing arguments for clarity— only to have the asker comment "Congratulations! That's how I did it!" So, I prompt askers for context in order to gauge whether they actually need my help.

Comment: Well, I have found a (partial) solution, but I cannot prove that there are no other solutions.

Comment: @AndrejJakobčič: Please include your (partial) solution as part of the question. This will let people know the level at which you are attacking the problem, and it will also save them the time of duplicating your effort; moreover, someone may be able to see in your work a key element that suggests that there are (or are not) other solutions.